# Why is my switch-statement only running once?

Tags: javascript, button, switch-statement

So I want my switch statement to check the "width" of my Navigation Bar when I click a button, and then act accordingly. But it only checks the first case and runs that code.

On first click:
Check the width is equal to 0px. 
Change the width to 100%. 
(Which is does fine).

On Second click:
Check the width is equal to 100%.
Change the width to 0px.
(Which it doesn't do).

I know this is probably rather simple, but I am still new to JavaScript, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    var bttn = document.getElementById('navRevealBttn');

    bttn.addEventListener('click', function(){

    var nav = document.getElementById('navBar');
    var style = getComputedStyle(nav);
    var width = style.width;

    switch (width) {
      case '0px': 
        IsIt1();
        break;

      case '500px' : 
        IsIt2();
        break;
    }
    });

    function IsIt1() {
      navBar.style.width = '500px';
      navBar.style.height = 'auto';
      navUl.style.fontSize = '25px'; 
    }

    function IsIt2() {
      navBar.style.width = '0px';
      navBar.style.height = '0';
      navUl.style.fontSize = '0px'; 
    }
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DylanT17/hk51woe4/2/

Comment: You only assigned to `width` once, on pageload

Comment: calculate the width inside the click event

Comment: will never get `'100%'` returned as  computed style value either regardless if that's how you set it or not

Comment: @CertainPerfomance How would I assign it more than once?

Comment: @Rishab Do yo mean I should place the width variable inside the function?

Comment: @DylanT25 yes... check it when event occurs

Comment: @charlietfl Noted - I will adjust that now.

Comment: yes place all code regarding  the width inside function

Comment: @Rishab I have placed it inside, but it is still the same???

Comment: Can you add complete html code too ?

Comment: @Rishab I have added the complete code into JSFiddle - just click on the black square (in JSFIddle) to see the switch-statement at work.

Comment: Okay I'm checking the code wait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code was navBar was adding the overlay on the button, which don't allow you to trigger click event.checks solution below

```js
var bttn = document.getElementById('navRevealBttn');


bttn.addEventListener('click', function(){ 
var nav = document.getElementById('navBar');
var style = getComputedStyle(nav);
var width = style.width;console.log(width)
switch (width) {
  case '0px': 
    IsIt1();
    break;
    
  case '500px' : 
    IsIt2();
    break;
}
},false);

function IsIt1() {
  navBar.style.width = '500px';
  navBar.style.height = 'auto';
  navUl.style.fontSize = '25px';   
  navBar.style.marginTop = '100px'; 

}

function IsIt2() {
  navBar.style.width = '0px';
  navBar.style.height = '0';
  navUl.style.fontSize = '0px';   
  navBar.style.marginTop = '100px'; 

}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#navBar {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#navRevealBttn {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
#navUl {
  list-style: none;
  width: 20%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  row-gap: 20px;
  height: auto;
  border: 2px solid black;
  font-size: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    
    <article id="navRevealBttn"></article>
    <div id="navBar">
      <ul id="navUl">
        <li class="navLi">Hi There</li>
        <li class="navLi">Hi There</li>
        <li class="navLi">Hi There</li>
        <li class="navLi">Hi There</li>
        <li class="navLi">Hi There</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Rishab - I can't believe how simple that was lol